# Can I connect six 150W lights in sequence on #12 wire with a 20A breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, barn

I'm looking to use these 150w high bay UFO lights in my barn. Looking to install each one in a JB on the ceiling and daisy chain 6 of them together on a 20a circuit using 12/2. Ideally I will have 2 circuits of 6 lights each. It's 18g wire coming from the light.

I'm just looking for reassurance that I'm OK with the wattage using 6 of these with 12/2 and 20A.

Thank you in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: When UL listed then they are safe to use with their 18 gauge wire.  You must use 12 gauge when making the circuit to the lights and then use wire nuts to connect to the 18 gauge of the lights.

Comment: Appreciate the reply that was my plan. I was just thrown off initially with it being 18g.

Comment: You might consider using 14/2 with 15A breakers.  Installing 12 of these working overhead, you'll appreciate the relative ease of working with the thinner wire and since you're provisioning 2 circutis just for these lights you'll still only be at half circuit capacity.  Also, 1800 total actual watts of LED (not equivalent) light .... I assume this is a large space ? and so you'll save a little on cable.

Comment: The conductor sizes are specified so that you can plan installation with appropriate connectors.   Very few appliances require their innards to be protected by your circuit breaker.

Answer (score 3):

This is fine, based on the UL listing more than anything else. UL has various tables, formulas, testing protocols, etc. to make sure that all the components in a device are sized correctly and work together in a safe manner. That allows, among other things, for smaller wires attached and/or inside a fixture than are permitted for the circuit from the breaker to the fixture.

One big reason this is allowed is that the wires on/in the fixture are normally going to handle a very low amount of current. A 20A (12 AWG wiring) circuit has to handle 16A continuously, 20A for short periods of time and more than 20A for very short periods of time (e.g., motor startup). Similarly, a 15A (14 AWG wiring) circuit has to handle 12A continuously, 15A for short periods of time and more than 15A for very short periods of time. But the light fixture wiring only carries the current **for that fixture**.

In your example, each circuit will have 6 x 150W = 900W = 7.5A nominal current. That is well within the range of 14 AWG wire on a 15A circuit. In fact, you could put both strings of lights (but nothing else) on a single 20A circuit (15A continuous usage), though splitting the lights into two circuits has some advantages - e.g., if you turn off one circuit for maintenance you still have plenty of light. Even if you could use 18 AWG wiring in regular building circuits, the limit would be way below 15A (I can't find a definitive number, probably because NEC doesn't allow it normally.) But it just doesn't matter because the 18 AWG wires involved will *only* carry the current of an individual light - ~ 1.25A. While there may be some higher startup current, I suspect the limitation on wire size (i.e., why not use something even smaller than 18 AWG) has more to do with (a) getting wire at a reasonable price that has proper insulation (which is based on the voltage, so at least 300V here but typically rated 600V) and (b) physical strength.

This is a general rule with electrical devices - each device is designed only to carry the current it actually needs. One key exception is 15A receptacles. Because a 20A circuit can include 15A receptacles and receptacles are often used as part of a circuit by making use of two sets of screw terminals, the receptacles actually are designed for 20A pass-through current even though the receptacles themselves each only supply 15A (keyed to prevent 20A plugs from using a 15A receptacle).